# how to set radio buttons initial value on Netbeans for a Java desktop application?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jradiobutton

This app I'm working on has three radio buttons, but I need to open the JFrame with one of them selected and the other two not.

Upon the JFrame load, I call the following method:

```
private void initJRadio() {
    jRadioButton1.setSelected(false);
    jRadioButton2.setSelected(true);
    jRadioButton3.setSelected(false);
}
```

But I get the following exception upon loading the JFrame:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at StockJFrame.initJRadio(StockJFrame.java:139)

Where StockJFrame is the class name and 139 is the line number for "jRadioButton1.setSelected(false);"

On the Source pane for this class, Netbeans has added these lines:

```
jRadioButton1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
jRadioButton2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
jRadioButton3 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();

jRadioButton1.setText(/*label value*/);
jRadioButton1.setToolTipText(/*some tooltip text*/);
jRadioButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});

jRadioButton2.setText(/*label value*/);
jRadioButton2.setToolTipText(/*some tooltiptext*/);
jRadioButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jRadioButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});

jRadioButton3.setText(/*label value*/);
jRadioButton3.setToolTipText(/*some tooltip text*/);
jRadioButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jRadioButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});
```

How to correctly set this up?

Comment: Make sure the object is actually initialized.
    jRadioButton1 = new JRadioButton();

Comment: At some point in your code, the `jRadioButton1` and others must be (they probably already are) initialized through a `jRadioButton1 = new JRadioButton()`, as pointed out above. Find out where this is happening and make sure `initJRadio()` is only called  **after** that.

Comment: From you radio button names I assume you created them using the visual editor. You could also add a `ButtonGroup`, set the button group of each of your radio buttons to that group, and set one radio button as selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point in your code, the `jRadioButton1` (and others) must be (they probably already are) initialized through a `jRadioButton1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton()`.

If I'm not mistaken, NetBeans generated code, by default, does that initialization in a method called `initComponents()`. Also, `initComponents()` is usually called at the constructor.

Find out where the initialization is taking place (`initComponents()` or elsewhere) and make sure `initJRadio()` is only called  **after** that.

**Update:**

After you posted more of your code, you can put the `initJRadio()` call right after the last command you pasted. (Namely, `jRadioButton3.addActionListener(new ... });`).

PS.: The `java.lang.NullPointerException` means that your object is yet `null`, that is, as pointed above, it has not yet been initialized.